# Selenium WebDriver using JavaScript

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm new to Selenium WebDriver and trying to automate the online shopping site "amazon.co.uk". My intention is to navigate to a particular page of the site and retrieve the sellers names,their respective URL's and write the final output to an Excel Sheet. I was able to print all the above mentioned details in the console but couldn't write them into an Excel Sheet.

Below is the piece of code that I had come up with:

```
package Selenium.src.com.amazon.automation;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class AmazonTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        try {
            driver.get("https://www.amazon.co.uk");
            Thread.sleep(1000);;
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(150, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            String PageTitle = driver.getTitle();
            System.out.println("Page Title is :" + PageTitle );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Driver not reachable");
        }
        WebElement wb = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Shop by']"));
        WebElement wb1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Electronics  & Computers']"));
        Actions act = new Actions(driver);
        act.moveToElement(wb).build().perform();
        act.moveToElement(wb1).build().perform();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Headphones']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        // To wait until the next page loads
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        jse.executeScript("scroll(0, 1000);");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//span[text()='See more'])[2]")).click();
        List<WebElement> topSellers = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='refinementList']//a"));
        //  int sellersCount = topSellers.size();
        System.out.println("The Number Of Top Sellers is :" + topSellers.size());

        for(int i=0;i<topSellers.size();i++)
        {
            //To print the list of Top Sellers and their number of products
            System.out.println(topSellers.get(i).getText());
            //To print the link of individual seller
            System.out.println(topSellers.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
            /*To get the page title for individual seller
            String PageTitle = driver.getTitle();
            System.out.println("Page Tile for this seller is :" +PageTitle);
            topSellers.get(i).click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.navigate().back();
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleIs("Amazon.co.uk: see all sellers"));
            driver.navigate().refresh();*/
        }
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

Can anybody please help me to achieve this requirement

I'm trying to write the below mentioned data into the Excel sheet...
1. Seller Name
2. Number of products of the seller
3. href link for individual seller

Please find the Screenshot for the same.

[Image shows the list of TopSellers and the count of their products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/et9bn.png)

Comment: Can you please provide some more information as below: 1. Which information exactly do you want to write into the Excel Sheet ? 2. How is the information depicted on the site? Tabular format? Dropdown? Modal Dropdown ? 3. Can you please provide some snapshot? 4. Provide the HTML DOM as well.

Comment: Are you able to sysout the stuff you want to write to Excel? I don't see any code where you are actually trying to write to Excel. I would suggest that you write to a CSV file and just open that in Excel. It will save you a lot of time.